# python flickr api for group search and get image data set

Tags: python, flickr

Is there any python flickr api where i can hit the group url and get the all the latest image data ?

I have an url like :

```
https://www.flickr.com/groups/caterpillarequipment/
```

I want to get all the latest images data set.
I try to do it with flickrapi lib but able to figure out any ways till now.
I'm new to flickr api dont know how to get this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get all of the info for a group's pool use the `flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos` API call, like this:

```
import flickrapi
from pprint import pprint

api_key = 'your api key'
secret = 'your secret key'
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret, format='parsed-json')

group_id = '544735@N20'    # caterpillarequipment's group_id
response = flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos(group_id=group_id, per_page=3)
pprint(response)
{u'photos': {u'page': 1,
             u'pages': 1033,
             u'perpage': 3,
             u'photo': [{u'dateadded': u'1428715622',
                         u'farm': 8,
                         u'id': u'16912446348',
                         u'isfamily': 0,
                         u'isfriend': 0,
                         u'ispublic': 1,
                         u'owner': u'71639059@N00',
                         u'ownername': u'ocrr4204',
                         u'secret': u'311b63f966',
                         u'server': u'7685',
                         u'title': u'Dufresne Construction 146 a CAT D7H bulldozer Ottawa, Ontario Canada 04252007 \xa9Ian A. McCord'},
                        {u'dateadded': u'1428713719',
                         u'farm': 8,
                         u'id': u'16896411327',
                         u'isfamily': 0,
                         u'isfriend': 0,
                         u'ispublic': 1,
                         u'owner': u'62532775@N03',
                         u'ownername': u'Jibup',
                         u'secret': u'76dc9110ed',
                         u'server': u'7695',
                         u'title': u'Caterpillar'},
                        {u'dateadded': u'1428554028',
                         u'farm': 8,
                         u'id': u'17058845816',
                         u'isfamily': 0,
                         u'isfriend': 0,
                         u'ispublic': 1,
                         u'owner': u'73369431@N07',
                         u'ownername': u'Stephen Ball Photography',
                         u'secret': u'607f522144',
                         u'server': u'7705',
                         u'title': u'One Up One Down'}],
             u'total': u'3097'},
 u'stat': u'ok'}
```

I have used a small page size of 3 for demo purposes - the default is 100 and the maximum is 500. This means that you will need to make multiple calls to the service to retrieve all of the photos. You could loop like this:

```
group_pool_photos = []
group_id = '544735@N20'    # caterpillarequipment's group_id
page = 1
success = True
while True:
    response = flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos(group_id=group_id, page=page)
    if response['stat'] != 'ok':
        print 'Error occurred in flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos'
        pprint(response)
        success = False
        break

    if len(response['photos']['photo']) == 0:
        break

    group_pool_photos.extend(response['photos']['photo'])
    page += 1

if success:
    print 'Info for all pool photos successfully retrieved. Total photos {}'.format(len(group_pool_photos))
```

At the end of this `group_pool_photos` should contain all photo info.

N.B. It's possible that the pool might change due to additions or deletions of photos during the retrieval process, so you might want to try and detect that by comparing the total in successive responses.

Comment: To get all of the photos in a group, you must authenticate as a group member before calling flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos.  E.g.,
`flickr.authenticate_via_browser(perms='read')`. If you don't authenticate as a group member, private images and images owned by Flickr users that have permissions set to hide stuff from public searches will be excluded from the results of the API call.

Comment: How do you get the group ID?